# Explanation/example of the proper use of an XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am beyond confused with XML Schemas. I believe they are used to define custom elements to be used as a template.

Say I have the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- definition of simple elements -->
  <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string"/>

  <!-- definition of attributes -->
  <xs:attribute name="choice_value" type="xs:int"/>

  <!-- definition of complex elements -->
  <xs:element name="choice">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="text" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="choice_value" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Can someone please provide a detailed example, a complete one element XML file on how I use and import this schema? I am able to import or include it, when I try to declare my element, it says and can't be found. Google results only show one how to import, but not actually apply it.

Comment: Ill even take a comment. I really need pointed in the right direction.

Comment: A schema is just a language verification of an xml file.  It is not needed for importing an xml file because it is assume the application that generated the xml generated it properly.  The schema is useful in reading/parsing an xml file since it provides all the tags and type you would expect in the xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An XML Schema defines an XML vocabulary (what element and attribute names may be used) and grammar (how elements and attributes may be composed).**

Per your XSD, the following XML documents, for example, would be valid:

1. `<text/>`
2. `<text>asdf</text>`
3. `<choice choice_value="1"><text/></choice>`
4. `<choice choice_value="1"><text>asdf</text></choice>`

Association of an XML document with an XML Schema is often done via `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` or `xsi:schemaLocation` attributes on the root element.  Here is an example of how to hint to the XML processor that the XML Schema to use to validate XML document #4 above is `try.xsd`:

```
<choice choice_value="1"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
    <text>asdf</text>
</choice>
```

Be aware that there are other mechanisms to associate an XSD with an XML document such as [XML Catalogs](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/14809/xml-catalogs.html), or command line or GUI-set preferences particular to any given XML processor.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I was having such a problem with this.